# Gitlab Integrations: "Google chat notifications" for multiple channels

Tags: gitlab, integration, google-chat

I have configured a Gitlab integration with Google chat so that only and notifications correctly reach only one chat from the default branch, master.

But I find myself looking for a way to show the notifications for master in one channel and in another for the other branches.

I know that you can only do a Google chat integration in Gitlab, but is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of the builtin "integrations" settings. You can only configure one instance of each of the builtin integrations. In the case of the google chat integration, only one channel can be configured this way.

If you need notifications for multiple channels, there are at least two ways you might work around this limitation:

1. Implement your own [webhook receiver](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) that [leverages the Google Chat incoming webhook api](https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/webhooks)
2. call google chat APIs from your CI/CD pipeline (some GitLab CI functionality like `when: on_failure` may also be useful in this case)